# Python Runtime error in Online Judge

Tags: python, runtime-error

So I'm trying to solve the following problem from the UVa online judge: https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=1998

I've written the following code in Python:

```
while True:
    try:
        aux = [0, 0]
        books = int(input())
        prices = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
        money = int(input())
        prices.sort()
        for i in range(0, len(prices)-1, 1):
            for j in range(len(prices)-1, 0, -1):
                if(j == i):
                    break
                if(prices[i] + prices[j] == money):
                    aux[0] = prices[i]
                    aux[1] = prices[j]

print("Peter should buy books whose prices are %d and %d. \n" %   (aux[0], aux[1]))


except EOFError:
    break
```

I think it may have something to do with the way the input is given; if every test case is separated by a blank line, how do I ignore this line and keep on reading input until EOF?

Comment: I see some indentation problems here

Comment: Would you like to share the error message?

Comment: You may want to us `sys.stdin` vs. `input()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easier using `sys.stdin` than input. Using a generator makes error handling easy as the `for` will terminate when it reaches the EOF (`next()` throws `StopIteration`):

```
import sys
from itertools import combinations

def load():
    while True:
        books = int(next(sys.stdin))
        prices = sorted(int(x) for x in next(sys.stdin).split())
        money = int(next(sys.stdin))
        yield books, prices, money
        next(sys.stdin)  # Skip blank line

for b, ps, m in load():
    i, j = max(((i,j) for i, j in combinations(ps, 2) if i+j == m), key=lambda x: x[0])
    print("Peter should buy books whose prices are {} and {}".format(i, j))
    print('')
```

Output:

```
Peter should buy books whose prices are 40 and 40

Peter should buy books whose prices are 4 and 6
```